# IDEA: viewing Scala (core) sources in a non-SBT project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am working on a Scala project in **IDEA 2016.2.4** with **scala-sdk-2.11.7** configured as a dependency.

Now I want to see e.g. how Ordered.class was implemented. But when I open the class, I only see lines like

```
  def <(that : A) : scala.Boolean = { /* compiled code */ }
```

IDEA says “Sources not found” with buttons “Download...” and “Attach Sources...”.

Clicking on  **Download...** results in **Sources for 'scala-library.jar' not found**.

Then I tried **Attach Sources...** with [scala-sources-2.11.7.tar.gz](https://github.com/scala/scala/archive/v2.11.7.tar.gz) just to realize, that it does not like .tar.gz (but there is [no source jar available](http://www.scala-lang.org/download/2.11.7.html#Other_resources)).

Am I now forced to convert the project to SBT or is there any other option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the docs and sources in regular .jar format on Maven Central: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.11.7/

I would still recommend using sbt ;)

Comment: In the meantime I solved it using cygwin with `tar -xzf scala-2.11.7.tar.gz` and then `jar.exe cf scala-2.11.7-src.jar scala-2.11.7`. But your solution looks better :D